# Referential Integrity and HBase

Tags: database, transactions, nosql, hbase, acid

One of the first sample schemas you read about in the HBase FAQ is the Student-Course example for a many-many relationship. The schema has a Courses column in the Student table and a Students column in the Course table.

But I don't understand how in HBase you guarantee integrity between these two objects. If something were to crash between updating one table and before another, we'd have a problem.

I see there is a transaction facility, but what is the cost of using this on what might be every Put? Or are there other ways to think about the problem?

Answer (score 2):

We hit the same issue.

I have developed a commercial plugin for hbase that handles transactions and the relationship issues that you mention.  Specifically, we utilize DataNucleus for a JDO Compliant environment.  Our plugin is listed on this page  http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/datastores.html or you can go directly to our small blog http://www.inciteretail.com/?page_id=236.

We utilize JTA for our transaction service.  So in your case, we would handle the relationship issue and also any inserts for index tables (Hard to have an app without index lookup and sorting!).

Answer (score 1):

Without an additional log you won't be able to guarantee integrity between these two objects. HBase only has atomic updates at the row level. You could probably use that property though to create a Tx log that could recover after a failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to perform two INSERTs as a single unit of work, that means you have to use a transaction manager to preserve ACID properties.  There's no other way to think about the problem that I know of.

The cost is less of a concern that referential integrity.  Code it properly and don't worry about performance.  Your code will be the first place to look for performance problems, not the transaction manager.

Answer (score 0):

Logical  relational  models  use  two  main  varieties  of  relationships:  one-to-many  and
many-to-many. Relational databases model the former directly as foreign keys (whether
explicitly  enforced  by  the  database  as  constraints,  or  implicitly  referenced  by  your
application  as  join  columns  in  queries)  and  the  latter  as  junction  tables  (additional
tables where each row represents one instance of a relationship between the two main
tables). There is no direct mapping of these in HBase, and often it comes down to de-
normalizing the data.
 The first thing to note is that HBase, not having any built-in joins or constraints,
has little use for explicit relationships. You can just as easily place data that is one-to-
many in nature into HBase tables:. But
this is only a relationship in that some parts of the row in the former table happen to
correspond to parts of rowkeys in the latter table. HBase knows nothing of this rela-
tionship, so it’s up to your application to do things with it (if anything).